# TI-84 Plus CE even/odd function?

Tags: ti-basic

So I want to make a program that will use the Collatz Conjecture on numbers I put in, but I can't figure out a way to make the program be able to tell between even and odd numbers. I know it's x%2==0 for odd in Python, but I can't seem to find a function for it in the catalog in my calculator, or a way to algebraically do that. If anyone is familiar with that or has any suggestions, that'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a round or floor function? If floor(x / 2) == (x / 2) then x is even.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is customer support for consumer electronics, not a programming question.

Comment: I disagree. TI-BASIC is a programming language, and this is a programming question. The device on which programming is done doesn't determine a question's validity as a programming question.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 5):

`remainder(` only exists on newer firmware. The best way to do this, at no cost to your size, is to use `fPart(`, which is only one byte instead of two.

Here is an example:

```
[Your Number]->A
If fPart(A/2
Then
Disp "ODD
Else
Disp "EVEN
End
```

... which can be shortened to:

```
Disp sub("EVENODD ",1+8fPart(A/2),4
```

Comment: And the `fPart(A/2` works because the `fPart(` command returns the fractional part of a number, and the `If` conditional interprets any nonzero number to mean true.

Comment: Right. If you actually want the remainder of A/B, use `BfPart(A/B` instead.

Answer (score 4):

The TI-84+ uses an updated version of TI-83 TI-BASIC. You can use the `remainder()` function on this calculator to determine whether a number is divisible by 2.

`remainder(20/2)` evaluates to 0.

You can then use basic conditional logic to print whatever output you want!

For documentation on TI-BASIC, check out http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/

Comment: I never saw remainder( on my ti-84, but I use fPart( -it returns the decimal part of any number

Comment: @PrivateCaller `remainder(` was introduced in the 2.53 MP operating system. I would also recommend using `fPart(` if at all possible.

Comment: Nate, I know what you're trying to say, but remember that `remainder(` technically isn't TI-83 BASIC in the sense that TI-83 does not support the 2.53MP OS, which is the one that introduced the command.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more efficient way:

```
/*your number goes here*/

if fPart(Ans/2):Then
Disp "Odd
Else
Disp "Even
End
```

Putting the value of the number in your code automatically stores it inside the "Ans" variable.

**It would more efficient to use the "Ans" variable** in your if statement instead of using up additional memory by creating an another variable.

This is because the value of "Ans" is stored in a reserved part of the calculator's memory, which won't take up extra space.

It is also faster than "the real, complex, list, matrix, and string variables; and subsequently, you should try to use it as much as possible."

Source:

> http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/ans